# How do I get rid of popup errors when using win32com.client to change excell files with python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

My code is

```
import win32com.client as win32
import time
import sys
stock = "dd"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dad_app\\template\\template.xlsm')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Overview')
ws.Range("E8").Value = stock
wb.SaveAs('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dad_app\\data\\' + stock + '.xlsm')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

it gives me a popup twice :
[image]
But if I click continue, it works
How do I remove that popup?

Comment: In VBA you can use [On Error Resume Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement#on-error-resume-next). But I know nothing about python, so can't even check if it will work in your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to do that with python because I am using a module

Comment: I would imagine that this happens because you have set up your Excel sheet/its VBA modules to perform validation on the E8 cell, so that this actually has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: How do I change that?